# ios Image with clickable content

Tags: ios

I'm trying to figure out how i can have an image with click-able content. My simple prototype project require to load an image for example a car dashboard and allow the user click an area on that image to pop some information.I thought about using uiimageview and adding transparent custom uibutton Not sure if that is the correct/right way of doing it specially with allowing user to zoom ..etc . hope to get some points/Ideas how that can be accomplished.

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Hello there. Have you solved your problem. I am get stuck here?Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should enable the userInteraction for the UImageView and than add a UITapGestureRecognizer

```
  UIImageView *t = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"test"]];
  [t setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapper = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(mySelector:)];
  [t addGestureRecognizer:tapper];

  [tapper release];

  //Do what ever you want with the UIImageView

  [t release];
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick response. Using the UITapGestureREcongnizer seems to be more appealing . But how for example to detect that the user clicked the steering wheel  or the speedometer in mySelector: method ?

Comment: That should be asked in a separate question. The answer is goes deeper into handling touch (not "click" -- that's a bad word in the Cocoa-touch world!) events.

Comment: You would use `locationOfTouch:inView:` and figure out which co-ordinates relate to what, but why makes things hard for yourself? A `UIButton` does it all for you :)

Comment: I agree uibutton is the simplest way to implement it,  but my concerns i have to handle when the device rotated etc with that approach as well as zooming in/out.

Answer (score 4):

Yes a transparent `UIButton` is the way to do this